# alphanumeric to increasing numbers in R

Tags: r, alphanumeric

I have a table in R with a column of ID's like: '1A', '2A', '1B', '2B', etc.

I would like to convert them to numbers such as: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

I would appreciate any suggestion.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to convert to a factor, and then to numbers. that way there is no assumptions of sequential order.

```
df <- data.frame(list(
  IDs=c('1A', '2A', '1B', '2B'),
  vals=c(8,8,8,8)
))

df$IDs <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$IDs))
```

Comment: This one worked Goodl and its general

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(list(
  IDs=c('1A', '2A', '1B', '2B'),
  vals=c(8,8,8,8)
))
```

assuming that the IDs are in sequential order replace the `IDs` vector with a sequence of numbers starting at 1 and ending at the length of the data frame

```
df$IDs <- seq(1,nrow(df))
```

alternatively:

```
df$IDs <- seq_along(df$IDs)

  IDs vals
1   1    8
2   2    8
3   3    8
4   4    8
```

The `tidyverse` solution would be to use `row_number`

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% mutate(IDs = row_number())
```